# Apache Flink Kubernetes Job Arguments

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to setup a cluster (Apache Flink 1.6.1) with Kubernetes and get following error when I run a job on it:

```
2018-10-09 14:29:43.212 [main] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint  - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-10-09 14:29:43.214 [main] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint  - Registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterConfiguration.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.EntrypointClusterConfiguration.<init>(EntrypointClusterConfiguration.java:37)
    at org.apache.flink.container.entrypoint.StandaloneJobClusterConfiguration.<init>(StandaloneJobClusterConfiguration.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.container.entrypoint.StandaloneJobClusterConfigurationParserFactory.createResult(StandaloneJobClusterConfigurationParserFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.container.entrypoint.StandaloneJobClusterConfigurationParserFactory.createResult(StandaloneJobClusterConfigurationParserFactory.java:42)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.parser.CommandLineParser.parse(CommandLineParser.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.container.entrypoint.StandaloneJobClusterEntryPoint.main(StandaloneJobClusterEntryPoint.java:153)
```

My job takes a configuration file (file.properties) as a parameter. This works fine in standalone mode but apparently the Kubernetes cluster cannot parse it

job-cluster-job.yaml:

```
args: ["job-cluster", "--job-classname", "com.test.Abcd", "-Djobmanager.rpc.address=flink-job-cluster",
       "-Dparallelism.default=1", "-Dblob.server.port=6124", "-Dquery.server.ports=6125", "file.properties"]
```

How to fix this?

Update: The job was built for Apache 1.4.2 and this might be the issue, looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

The job was built for 1.4.2, the class with the error (EntrypointClusterConfiguration.java) was added in 1.6.1 (https://github.com/apache/flink/commit/ab9bd87e521d19db7c7d783268a3532d2e876a5d#diff-d1169e00afa40576ea8e4f3c472cf858) it seems, so this caused the issue. 
We updated the job's dependencies to point to new 1.6.1 release and the arguments are parsed correctly.